# Simplest Razor page in ASP.NET 5 vNext

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I'm really excited about the efforts put into ASP.NET 5 so far and have been messing around with it a bit. On my quest to understand things a bit better, I tried doing (searching for info) a single Razor driven page, but without success. I can work with MVC, but I'm wondering how should one be able to create the leanest and smallest project to run a single Default.cshtml page with the Razor template engine.

Answer (score 1):

See the sample project from the ASP.NET team here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta4/HelloMvc

(*See this sample project in it's context. A simple razor page would be useless or it would be one gigantic mess of spaghetti code*)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is more conceptual than practical. It is simply interesting to know whether it is possible to run a single razor driven page on Linux without any MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's always been possible to use the low level razor APIs to render pages. You can see a console application here https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/src/PageGenerator

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I believe you have misunderstood me.